# Whether hash of arrays contains data from an array

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash

I have an array of people's ID like this:

```
people_id = [1111, 2222, 3333, 4444, 5555]
```

and a hash with nested arrays as values like this:

```
hash = {1234 => [1111], 1235 => [2222, 4444], 1236 => [1111, 1111, 5555, 1236]}
```

I need to interrogate each array `hash`, comparing it to `people_id` array. If any hash array contains more than one of the values from `people_id`, then I need to return the keys, so in this example I would expect to return `1235` and `1236`, because:

- `1234` is false (only one element from `people_id` is present)
- `1235` is true (`2222` and `4444` are both present)
- `1236` is true (`1111` and `5555` are both present)

Can anyone advise?

Comment: The logic is not clear. How are `1111` and `5555` relevant to `1235`?

Comment: Also, with `1236`, how are the non-unique occurrences of `1111` in `hash` counted? Do they count as one, or as two?

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out sawa - there was a typo in the 3rd bullet point, it should have been 1236, not 1235. Have updated this now.

Comment: re non-unique occurrences of '1111', the logic needs to count them as one

Comment: Also, why is there a -4 next to my question? Have I been down-voted for something? Happy to learn protocol so would be useful to understand why

Comment: The problem you are describing seems pretty abstract and therefore hard to understand. Why is it relevant to specify you have an array of user ids if you do not explain what the hash actually is?

Comment: I didn't want to convolute the code with too much story @SirDarius but happy to expand on it. The hash keys are Id's for a class of students, the value in arrays indicate where a comment has been left for the student. The people_id array are the class teachers , so the exercise was to discover in which cases a student had received a comment from more than one teacher

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
hash.select{|_, v| (v & people_id).length > 1}.keys
# => [1235, 1236]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
hash = {
  1234 => [1111],
  1235 => [2222, 4444],
  1236 => [1111, 1111, 5555, 1236]
}
array = [1111, 2222, 3333, 4444, 5555]
hash.each_with_object([]) do |(k, v), acc|
  acc << k if (v & array).size > 1
end
#⇒ [1235, 1236]
```

Here we iterate through the hash object, checking if the intersection of the value and the original array contains more that one element, and adding a key to the accumulator if so.

Please note, that `(v & array).size` would be a good merit if and only `array` is guaranteed to be unique.

Comment: `(v & array).size > 1` this one rocks!

Comment: Your added note is not very accurate. Actually, `v & array` would work only if the hash's arrays are unique but it doesn't matter whether `array` is unique. `array & v` would work only if `array` is unique.

Comment: @sawa what I meant (from OP’s example we can see that hash’’s values are not necessarily unique,) that the above fails to detect `[1,1,1] & [1,1]`.

Comment: Right. What matters is that the hash's value is unique. Whether `array` is unique does not matter.

Comment: I think this is the one I need! :) If I'm understanding it correctly, if a hash had array [1111, 1111] the key would not be returned as there is only one unique element present, yes?

Comment: @Adam yes, and you might try it yourself, which is way faster than awaiting an answer here.

Comment: I did try it but the real data is much bigger so taking some time to check. That said, I could have created some dummy data to test the logic, so I concede the point ;)

Answer (score 0):

Note I am new to programming so here is my attempt that uses two helper variables and set:

```
require 'set'

peopleIDArray = [1111, 2222, 3333, 4444, 5555]
peopleHash = {1234 => [1111], 1235 => [2222, 4444], 1236 => [1111, 1111, 5555, 1236]}
result = Set[]

peopleHash.each do |key, value|
  foundOnePerson = false
  foundTwoPerson = false

  value.each { |id|
    if peopleIDArray.include? id and !foundOnePerson
      foundOnePerson = true
      next
    end

    if peopleIDArray.include? id and !foundTwoPerson
      foundTwoPerson = true
    end

    if foundOnePerson and foundTwoPerson
      result.add(key)
    end
  }
end

p result.to_a  # => [1235, 1236]
```